# Unable to install VPN Unlimited on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, vpn

I am unable to install VPN unlimited on Ubuntu 18.04 despite following the instructions on the official website (the instructions are quite outdated as they pertain to Ubuntu 14.04). I am currently stuck as I am getting messages such as:

```
  user $  sudo dpkg -i vpn-unlimited_4.22-amd64_001_release_STANDALONE.deb
    Selecting previously unselected package vpn-unlimited.
    (Reading database ... 216364 files and directories currently installed.)
    Preparing to unpack vpn-unlimited_4.22-amd64_001_release_STANDALONE.deb ...
    Unpacking vpn-unlimited (4.22) ...
    dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of vpn-unlimited:
     vpn-unlimited depends on libcurl3 (>= 7.22.0); however:
      Package libcurl3 is not installed.
     vpn-unlimited depends on iproute; however:
      Package iproute is not installed.

    dpkg: error processing package vpn-unlimited (--install):
     dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
    Processing triggers for systemd (237-3ubuntu10) ...
    Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-20) ...
    Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
    Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-1ubuntu3.18.04.1) ...
    Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-11ubuntu1) ...
    Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
    Errors were encountered while processing:
     vpn-unlimited
```

Comment: dpkg does NOT handle dependencies. Simply read the error messages. Identify the list of missing packages, and tell apt to install those packages for you (`sudo apt-get install libcurl3 iproute`). Then try installing the vpn-unlimited package again.

Comment: VPN Unlimited app is currently broken in 18.04. I've notified the developers and they're working on a fix (an updated app).

Comment: @user535733 libcurl3 won't install on 18.04 due to libcurl4 being there, and hence, the VPN Unlimited app won't install.

Comment: Thank you @heynnema. I purchased a lifetime VPN unlimited app for $39 via Java Code Geeks and I was disappointed that I could not get it to work. But this is great news! Thanks! Do they have an eta as to when the new application will come out?

Comment: @Al-geBra no ETA, but they're usually pretty fast about it.

Comment: @heynnema I am a bit concerned as Ubuntu 18.04 has been out for a few months now. I guess I will give it some more time. Hopefully, they will have something in July.

Comment: @Al-geBra go to https://my.keepsolid.com/products/vpn/ and configure and download individual VPN config files and that'll work for you until the app is ready.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/40779/how-do-i-install-a-deb-file-via-the-command-line

Comment: @DavidFoerster Not a dup. OP already used the `dpkg -i` command to try and install this app. The problem is that the app isn't currently compatible with 18.04 for the reasons that I speak of earlier.

Comment: @heynnema: The accepted answer to the linked question explains that `dpkg` doesn't resolve dependencies but that a subsequent `apt-get install -f` will. Whether those are satisfiable is a different matter (and we couldn't tell without knowledge of the result because OP may have configured suitable package repositories).

Comment: @DavidFoerster please be the 5th person to mark this question for reopen.

Comment: @heynnema: I'm already among those people.

Comment: A new release for ubuntu 18.04 bionic is out, https://www.vpnunlimitedapp.com/en/downloads/linux

Comment: Thanks, I have it now. I noticed via wireshark that it sometimes encrypts traffic via OpenVPN and sometimes does not.

Comment: 3rd October 2018, I still have the same issue